# Drawer too wide

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, drawers

I replaced all my kitchen cabinets with Lowes Arcadia cabinets. I made measurements of all my previous cabinets and placed my order using the same dimensions. Everything fits except for one 24x35 cabinet:

[image]

The old cabinet I replaced was 24x35 as well, but the drawers were narrower. Without the pull knob on the right perpendicular drawer, I am barely able to pull out the left side drawer. I am thinking, should I cut the face of the top left drawer on the far right side so I have enough clearance to pull out the drawer? Maybe leave the cut out face attached to the cabinet for appearance's sake? Or should I just suck it up and buy a smaller 18x35 cabinet? I'm not thrilled about dropping another hundred bucks because of less than 2 inches; also, the smaller cabinet would be waste of space on its right side (about 6 inches of dead space).

Note that while drilling left side cabinet to attach it to the cabinet besides it (the kitchen sink base cabinet) with a poor quality Kobalt titanium bit, the bit broke off and was impossible to remove without digging it out of the wood. So the cabinet is slightly damaged and not possible to return to Lowes.

Comment: It looks like you could trim the drawer face down to clear but that might show the slide if you go two far.

Comment: Did you or a Lowes representative do this install? If it was someone from Lowes, I'd be agitating to make this their problem. (And parenthetically, how'd the granite get set before this became an issue?)

Comment: I did the install. My first time

Comment: I'm assuming you remembered to utter the appropriate carpentry adjectives on discovering the interference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know...and the cabinet "salesman" didn't offer to explain about the clearances needed or the "closure" trim needed in the corner due to a narrower cabinet either...very helpful wasn't he.

So, I don't see an easy fix without it looking like a mistake, so, I'd buy the narrower cabinet and chalk it up to experience. Be sure to get the 2" - 3" wide trim that runs vertically in the corner. (By the way, will the right hand drawer clear the left hand cabinet pull without a vertical "closure" trim too.)

Remember, the kitchen is a key element in the resale of the house...you want it top-notch. Buyers spend some time in the kitchen when checking out a house to buy.

Answer (score 3):

No idea how "handy" you are or have the skills or tools available but there is a trick you could try.

You could reshape the drawer body to be a parallelogram, and offset the sliders so the drawer pulls out to an angle. When closed it would look normal.

[image]

Obviously you would need to draw that up to match your angles appropriately. Getting past the handle on the other drawer would be the biggest issue.

You may need to buy a new sheet of plywood for the drawer floor though and you will lose a bit of inside drawer width. The rear board of the drawer (and the one behind the facia if there is one) would need to be shortened the appropriate amount. Note: The facia needs to be offset.

Comment: This is a clever idea but a big consideration is the cost trade off. The OP has stated that a proper narrower cabinet would be "a hundred bucks". How much the custom drawer ends up costing may make the idea not so attractive.

Comment: He should be able to adapt the current drawer though @MichaelKaras if he has the tools and is brave enough. It's a one shot adventure :)

Comment: I agree that it may be possible. By the looks of the cabinet materials (especially the front panel) this appears to be laminated MDF or particle board.....not great stuff to rework.

Comment: @MichaelKaras.. True that.. Though the drawer box itself looks like cheap old pine. Fortunately, the facia he would not have to mess with.

Comment: Here is a note from an answer to a customer question at the Lowes web site. This came from the manufacturer DiamondNOW Customer Service. "The Arcadia doors have a DLV, Decorative Laminate Veneer finish over MDF panels. The cabinet sides are 1/2" furniture board. We do not recommend painting the cabinets, as it will void the warranty." Note that the drawer fronts are equivalent. At this time I suspect that "furniture board" is a particle board material.

Comment: That does not mention the drawer material though. Cabinet sides is something different @MichaelKaras. Anyhow, all he needs it to cut the rear and possible intermediate front board NOT the decorative front board. (Possibly with the help of the local hardware store). Then trim the floor to shape, then glue it back together. It's not that hard, as long as you get the drawing and cut angles right.

Comment: But hard to tell for sure without seeing the drawer in your hands.

Comment: I read more mfg answered questions at the Lowes web site. That brand uses furniture board for the drawer box too. You will likely see this for most mass market cabinets these days. This particular line of cabinets does use a maple face frame that is then laminated with the white material. Note I am not "dissing" your idea at all - in fact I upvoted your answer. I just think it is important to understand what is involved in terms of materials.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, :) Yes I do appreciate your input. All good points, and thanks for the vote. I will add.. on the bright side...in some ways "modern materials / manufacturing methods" helps here. The drawer will be easy to take apart. Or at least mine are, hardest part is stopping them LOL.

Answer (score 1):

If cutting from the side of the drawer face doesn't do it, you could dummy out the adjacent drawer and only lose a bit of drawer space.

If you felt really handy, you could make the wise drawer narrower and pad out the right side.